# Optionally turning off Model Validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

There are similar posts on here but none that cover exactly what I want to acheive.

I a class which implements attribute validation such as;

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public String Line1;
}
```

When I bind this property to my View, in certain circumstances (usually through exceptional circumstances) I want to remove the requirement for the user to enter a value into **Line1**

The Views I use tend to be loaded via Ajax and therefore validation is initiated using jQuery. Therefore I need a solution using jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might help - http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/15/37923/

Answer (score 0):

There is nice possibility by jQuery Validation Plugin. But you of course need the validation on client and on server, right, because client validation is for the good user, but worth nothing for the evil user.

Comment: I agree, and I am in fact implementing a server side solution, however certain fields need to be made not required for me to continue to the server in the first place. So is there a way to turn off validation that jquery-unobstrusive has added using the Model? At the minute I am removing the 'data' attributes on the Html objects then calling the jquery.validator.unobtrusive.parse() method before I submit the form. But I want a more elegant solution if there is one.